# probleme with printw, ncurses

Tags: c, ncurses

I need to use printw(); but it doesn't work, it just segfault.
I have used `initscr` and `endwin` but it doesn't change anything.

```
void    aff_battel(char **str)
{
  int   i;
  int   j;
  char  *str2;

  if ((str2 = malloc(sizeof(*str) * 23)) == NULL)
    return ;
  str2 = "---------------------\n\0";
  j = 0;
  i = 0;
  while (str[i] != NULL)
    {
      initscr();
      printw("---------------------\n\0"); /* it doesn't work */
      printw("%s", str2); /* here nether */
      endwin();
      i++;
    }
}
```

know i have put `initsrc();` at the start and endwin a the end of the loop but it still print me nothing

```
void    aff_battel(char **str)
{
  int   i;
  int   j;

  j = 0;
  i = 0;
  while (str[i] != NULL)
    {
      printw("---------------------\n");
      i++;
    }
  endwin();
}
```

Comment: Two problems: First you have a memory leak in that you allocate to `str2` and the you directly overwrite that pointer with a pointer to a literal string. Use e.g. `strcpy`. The other is that you should call `initscr` at the start of your program, and `endwin` at the end. Right now you create/destroy the window in every iteration.

Comment: Oh, and you don't have to add the terminating `'\0'`, it's added automatically (since you add it in the string, the string `"---------------------\n\0"` is actually 24 characters long, since the compiler adds an extra `'\0'` to the string).

Comment: And yet another thing, `sizeof(*str)` is the size of `char*`, i.e. 4 or 8 bytes depending on platform.

Comment: @Joachim I have put the initscr at the start and endwin at the end of the loop. I't doesn't segfault anymore but it print me nothing.

Comment: @leykan: Remove this `malloc()` call. You don't need of it. Also, Are you sure you should call   `initscr()` and `endwin()` **inside** loop?

Answer (score 0):

As Joachim Pileborg said, in the comments, `initscr()` should be at the start of your program, and `endwin()` at the end.

`initscr()` sets up an internal screen character map, to which `printw()` will write.

To copy the screen map to the actual screen you need to call `refresh()`. Without it, you will see nothing.

`endwin()` clears the screen and resets the terminal to normal.

Here is an example using your simplified function to demonstrate the ncurses functions. I have used `getch()` to make the program wait for a key press and then exit.

Note: In this example it would still display the text without the `refresh()` as `getch()` does a refresh too.

```
#include <ncurses.h>

void    aff_battel(char **str)
{
  int   i;
  int   j;

  j = 0;
  i = 0;
  while (str[i] != NULL)
  {
      printw("---------------------\n");
      i++;
  }
  refresh();
}

void main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    initscr();
    aff_battel(argv);
    getch();
    endwin();
}
```